# Kubernetes: Cluster node at 200% CPU Limit. Display math only? or potential issue?

Tags: kubernetes

0

So, let's say there's a cluster node, with 4 CPU cores.

It's running two pods. Each pod sets the CPU requirement at: 500m, but the CPU limit at 4000m.

running `kubectl` describe node  tells me CPU limit is at 8 (200%)

I understand it claims 200% because I have two pods, each setting its CPU limit at 4 CPU cores.

Is that just semantics or is there a potential issue? I mean, if both pods need to burst to 3 CPU cores (below each one's limit) it would not be physically possible, and they'd have to settle with less.

Is there a potential issue with the sum of all pod limits, exceeding their host node CPU capability? or is just an indication of what's been asked as CPU limit, knowing it may not be able to serve that -- after all, pods may not be aware of each other being in the same node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the limit is 200% of that node's CPUs. Yes, this is overcommmited, you have 4 CPUs not 8.

CPU is easy to throttle, the scheduler gives you less time slices. [From a Google post on resource requests and limits](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits):

> What if you have a Node where the sum of all the container Limits is
>   actually higher than the resources available on the machine?
>
> At this point, Kubernetes goes into something called an “[overcommitted state](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/resource-qos.md#qos-classes).” Here is where things get interesting. Because CPU can be
>   compressed, Kubernetes will make sure your containers get the CPU they
>   requested and will throttle the rest. Memory cannot be compressed, so
>   Kubernetes needs to start making decisions on what containers to
>   terminate if the Node runs out of memory.

This is a performance and capacity planning problem. A pod with a request of 500m but a limit of 4000m can burst to 8x its minimum to schedule. That could be a significant deviation in performance, depending on resource availability. If this is bad is conditional on if you want *predictable* performance or *opportunistic* use of capacity.

Not necessary for pods to be aware of what is to be scheduled on a node for this to affect capacity planning.

- For a truly single threaded container, there no point in a limit above 1000m.
- Limits of 4000m, when real consumption is 1200m, is greedy.

In aggregate, driving the oversubscription ratio up tends to make it more difficult to right-size the cluster and have predicable performance. Perhaps it becomes hard to tell whether doubling your nodes would improve performance, versus whether someone thought more was better without evidence.

Comment: Those are good points, thanks (especially single-threaded container by definition not using more than one CPU anyway)